# Is isRequired necessary for nested PropTypes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

Say I have this PropType defined:

```
Component.propTypes = {
  complicatedData: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      name: PropTypes.string,
      data: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.number)
    })
  ).isRequired,
};
```

If that data structure is required, is the `isRequired` attributed necessary for every level of that nested structure, or does the top-level `isRequired` at the end encompass everything inside?

Comment: Why haven't you just tried first?

Comment: Good point. I wasn't in a place in my file where I could stop and try it. But what's the harm in asking?

Comment: No harm surely. But you could have had the answer 8 minutes ago `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Ha true, but the file I'm refactoring is all screwed up and definitely will not run in the current state. Plus if someone knows the "why" in addition to the "what," it'll help me understand this piece of React better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The top level `isRequired` only checks if `complicatedData` is provided and is an array. You can give it an array with empty objects such as `[{}, {}]` and it'll pass the test based on your code.

If you want each element in your array `complicatedData` to have a `name` property, then you need to write:

```
Component.propTypes = {
  complicatedData: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      data: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.number)
    })
  ).isRequired,
};
```

Same if you want each element to have a `data` property.

Comment: So, does the top-level isRequired also make sure the top-level array contains objects, or would `isRequired` also be needed on `PropTypes.shape()`?

Comment: I don't think you need `isRequired` for `shape()`. The logic being that `arrayOf` is just making sure `complicatedData` is an array. Being an empty array is fine. In most real-world use cases (e.g., loading an array of comments), the array could be empty. So in my experience, I've never added `isRequired` to `shape()`.

Comment: @kylesimmonds you have to use `PropTypes.shape(...).isRequired`, or it would accept `complicatedData: [null]`